# How to enter OTP automatically without clicking another OTP text box?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm locating 1st element but how to continously enter other 3 digits of OTP
without locating.

Comment: add html pleace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WebElement currentElement = driver.switchTo().activeElement();
currentElement.sendKeys("something")
```

you can switch to active element and then send the value